# Test Step Move Properties on SoapUI with http post request

Tags: http, post, parameters, request, soapui

I created a Soap-UI Test-Suite with a Test-case.
This Test-case has a http request as Test-Step.
The method of the http request is post.
The http request has the Parameter `P_FILNR=1111&P_HDLNR=123456`.

How can I set/modify these Parameters with the Test-Step?

Comment: The source Property in the Property Transfer Test Step should a Properties Test Step

Comment: Would you mind showing screen shot explaining the problem? It is not sure what exactly the issue from the above question? What do you mean by modifying these parameters?

Comment: use custom properties. If you want to change them dynamically use a groovy step to change values before your HTTP request

Comment: use test step [properties](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html) and [propery expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) to utilize them in groovy . You can also use expansion directly in your XML test request. Also look at [REST parameters](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html)

Comment: I resolved the Problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

as Mentioned by @A Joly above here is the code which can help you. I have used the custom property and a groovy script

[image]

First of all you can mention the property name under the value like ${#TestCase#address} <-- This means a test case property with the name address.

You can now add a groovy step with the below code

```
def values=["India", "Russia","USA"]

for(int i=0; i < 3 ; i++)
{
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("address",values[i])
testRunner.runTestStepByName("Request 1")
}
```

So what happens here is the test step which we have to run has the step name as "Request 1". We are setting the value of Address dynamically and running the step via Groovy.

Also you can disable the request 1 step so that it does not run when you run the suite because groovy will run the request 3 times for 3 values

[image]